# Expand $f(z) = {(z+1)^2\over z(z^3+1)}$ in a Laurent series about $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Trying to express this as a partial fraction have proved unsuccesful, and I can't find any examples which replicate a Laurent series that isnt either easy to turn into a partial fraction, or has an obvious $\frac{1}{z}$ expression. The closest I got was by expressing the $(z^3+1)^{-1}$ term as $1 - z^3 + z^6 - z^9\dots$ (which I believe is valid, as the annulus on which $z$ is analytic requires $\mod z$ to be less than $1$) which resulted in 
$$\frac{1}{z} + 2 + z - z^2 - 2z^3 - z^4 + z^5 + 2z^6 +z^7\dots,$$ 
and I lack the brainpower to spin that into a Laurent series.

I also suck at maths, and this is part of a module that is a maths addition to my non maths course, so if you think there's a very trivial answer and I'm just being super dumb that is very much a possibility.

Thanks!

Comment: You already have the series of $(1+z^3)^{-1}$. Then $z^{-1}(z+1)^2(1+z^3)^{-1}=(z+2+z^{-1})(1+z^3)^{-1}=z(1+z^{-1})+2(1+z^3)^{-1}+z^{-1}(1+z^{-1})$. Replace the occurrences of $(1+z^3)^{-1}$ with your series.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the only step left is to multiply the terms:
$$\frac{(z+1)^2}{z(z^3+1)}=\frac{z^2+2z+1}{z(1-(-z)^3)}=\frac{z+2+\frac{1}{z}}{1-(-z)^3}=\left(z+2+\frac{1}{z}\right)(1+(-z)^3+(-z)^6+\ldots)$$